# Adding CSS float to tags in a form makes background color disappear

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need to apply a background color to a form.
Unfortunately, whenever I add `float: left` to the `p` tags, the background color immediately disappears.

The HTML sample is as follows:

```
<form id='register'>
    <p><label for='name'> Name: </label>
    <input type='text' id='name' pattern='[a-zA-Z].{3,70}'> </input></p>
    <p><label> email: </label> 
    <input type='email' id='email' placeholder='abc@example.com'></input></p>
```

and the CSS that's causing this is as follows:

```
#register p{
float:left;
}
```

Why does the float property affect the background and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue, and happens because floating an element creates a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context).

To solve this, you can:

1. Float your form, too.
2. Apply `overflow: hidden` to your form.
3. Add a hard coded height to your form.

Answer (score 2):

**Change CSS to:**

```
#register p{
    float:left;
}

form {
    background-color:red;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/prashant_ghimire/Lw1prcd6/)

Answer (score 1):

it's normal as long you didn't clear the float:

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ym9otf6q/:

```
form { 
  background-color: yellowgreen; 
  overflow:hidden; // Clearing the float
}
p{ float:left; }
```

Here is some more details of this common issue: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Hope it helps :)